# Hyper parameter finetuning with ML Engine: Nan error when running with parallel trials

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nan, google-cloud-ml

In my finetuning job in Google ML Engine, some training configurations lead to a NaN loss and, consequently, error. I would like to be able of ignoring these trials, and keep finetuning with different parameters.

I am using a NanTensorHook with fail_on_nan_loss=False , which works successfully in ML Engine when no parallel trials are performed (maxParallelTrials: 1), but fails on multiple parallel trials (maxParallelTrials: 3).

Has anyone encountered this error before? Any idea on how to solve it?

This is my configuration file:

```
trainingInput:
 scaleTier: CUSTOM
 masterType: standard
 workerType: standard
 parameterServerType: standard
 workerCount: 4
 parameterServerCount: 1
 hyperparameters:
   goal: MAXIMIZE
   maxTrials: 5
   maxParallelTrials: 3
   enableTrialEarlyStopping: False
   hyperparameterMetricTag: auc
   params:
   - parameterName: learning_rate
    type: DOUBLE
    minValue: 0.0001
    maxValue: 0.01
    scaleType: UNIT_LOG_SCALE
   - parameterName: optimizer
    type: CATEGORICAL
    categoricalValues:
    - Adam
    - Adagrad
    - Momentum
    - SGD
   - parameterName: batch_size
    type: DISCRETE
    discreteValues:
    - 128
    - 256
    - 512
```

and this is how I set the NanTensorHook:

```
hook = tf.train.NanTensorHook(loss,fail_on_nan_loss=False)

train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
    loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step(),
    learning_rate=lr, optimizer=optimizer)

model_fn = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss,
    eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops, train_op=train_op,
    training_hooks=[hook])
```

The error message I get is:

```
Hyperparameter Tuning Trial #4 Failed before any other successful 
trials were completed. The failed trial had parameters: optimizer=SGD, 
batch_size=128, learning_rate=0.00075073617775056709, . The trial's ror 
message was: The replica worker 1 exited with a non-zero status of 1. 
Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): [...] 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 421, in 
train_and_evaluate executor.run() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 522, in run 
getattr(self, task_to_run)() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 532, in 
run_worker return self._start_distributed_training() File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 715, in 
_start_distributed_training saving_listeners=saving_listeners) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 352, in train 
loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 891, in 
_train_model _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, 
estimator_spec.loss]) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 546, in 
run run_metadata=run_metadata) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1022, 
in run run_metadata=run_metadata) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1113, 
in run raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1098, 
in run return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1178, 
in run run_metadata=run_metadata)) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 
617, in after_run raise NanLossDuringTrainingError 
NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training. The replica 
worker 3 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. 
Traceback (most recent call last): [...] File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 421, in 
train_and_evaluate executor.run() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 522, in run 
getattr(self, task_to_run)() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 532, in 
run_worker return self._start_distributed_training() File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 715, in 
_start_distributed_training saving_listeners=saving_listeners) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 352, in train 
loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 891, in 
_train_model _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, 
estimator_spec.loss]) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 546, in 
run run_metadata=run_metadata) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1022, 
in run run_metadata=run_metadata) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1113, 
in run raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1098, 
in run return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1178, 
in run run_metadata=run_metadata)) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 
617, in after_run raise NanLossDuringTrainingError 
NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training.
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I suspect that setting the maxParallelTrials greater than 1 may activate another hook in Tensrflow which may cause ordering issue and prevents hooks, such as tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugHook from running when nans appear in the network. NanTensorHook causes the program to crash before the after_run() method of those hooks run.  Please provide the error you get and confirm that the last value of the loss before the error is not NaN.

Comment: Hi Shahin, thank you for your reply. The loss does get NaN, which is why I would like to set the NaNTensorHook. I added the error in the log.

Comment: Deleting ActiveWorkers SubDIRs in the Tuner DIR for the trial, then  retrying the TF job on the failed workers once the the new Trial got started may resolve the issue. Other thing as a work around could be changing the optimizer (e.g. to adagrad) which may avoid NaN values.

Comment: I personally suspect that there is an internal issue with the NanTensorHook source code such that it can not support the multiple trials. In other words, since each trail only benefits from the information gained in completed trials and does not get access to the results of trials running at the same time, It is possible that locally they face some NaN values which can not be resolved by the NaNtensorhook. In other words, NaNtensorhook only checks the completed trials (The Total loss function).

Comment: Thank you for the insight, it is a shame that the NanTensorHook fails in this scenario, I'll try and fix the NanHook to listen on each model loss. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different trials in the hyperparameter tuning job are isolated during their runtime. So the hook added for one trial won't be influenced by other hooks in other trials.

I suspected that the issue is caused by the specific combination of hyperparameters for the trial. To confirm, I'd suggest you to run a regular training job with the hyperparameter values for the failed trial and see if the error will happen again.

And could you please send the project number and job id to `cloudml-feedback@google.com`, we can do more investigation.